# fetch all users and their number of records in another table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables **users** (user_id, name) and **license** (license_id,user_id)

I want to get all users with their number of records in license table.
Question seems to be simple but I am not able to figure out its query.

I tried like

```
SELECT * FROM `users` a left join license b on a.user_id=b.user_id
```

but this is giving me all rows of a and matched rows of b table while I want all rows of a and one another column with number of rows matched in b.

Please help me how to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name, COUNT(b.user_id)
  FROM `users` a 
  LEFT JOIN license b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
  GROUP BY user_id, NAME;
```

Output: [SEE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2796/3)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of matching user you should use count and group by

```
SELECT user_id, name, count(*)
FROM `users` a 
INNER join license b on a.user_id=b.user_id
Group by user_id, name
```

of you want only the count of matching

```
select count(*) 
FROM `users` a 
INNER join license b on a.user_id=b.user_id
```

This instead return  the count of number in license

```
  select count(*) 
  FROM `users` a 
  LEFT join license b on a.user_id=b.user_id
```

and then you can obtain the same number simply using

```
  select count(*) 
  from  license
```

otherwise if you want then number with alto the user don't matc then try

```
SELECT user_id, name, ifnull(count(*), 0)
FROM `users` a 
LEFT join license b on a.user_id=b.user_id
Group by user_id, name
```

Comment: inner join will not give all records of users table I think ?

Comment: Yes but an user that don't match the license seems non sense to me .. in your case .. then if you want try explain better ..

Comment: I have update the answer with some suggestion i hope useful

Comment: yes, I need all rows of users table with number of records in license table, your first query giving all rows with number of records in license table which are matched but in the same query I wish to get remaining users with 0 count. I tried this query "SELECT a.*, count(*) FROM `users` a  left join license b on a.user_id=b.user_id  Group by user_id" but it is giving 1 count for those which are remaining

Comment: Sorry, but it's giving me column name as 'ifnull(count(*), 0)' with value '1'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  U.user_id, U.name, COUNT(L.license_id) as licenseCount
FROM `users` U
LEFT JOIN license L ON U.user_id=L.user_id
GROUP BY U.user_id;
```

> Refer [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5acd9/1)